# How to automatically move element in available vertical space?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have elements on a web page.  For tablet breakpoints, the content will go 50% width and break up into two columns.  However, sometimes depending on the content, there are times when there are blank spaces that show up on the page.  Is there a way to place the elements into optimal positioning so that it takes up the available vertical space?  I do not have control of the markup.  **Please note: I don't have control of the content.  I just used random heights in this example, but they could be anything.**

I am looking for a solution that uses CSS or JS (jQuery).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's sample code:
http://jsfiddle.net/a8ar7eyx/

In the above example, I would like the green box to move up so that there isn't any white space.

[image: Screenshot]

```
CSS:

.container { width: 100%; }
.col { 
    float: left; 
    width: 50%; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    border: 0 solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-left-width: 18px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}

HTML: 

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" style="height: 900px; background-color: blue;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" style="height: 500px; background-color: red;"></div>
        <div class="col" style="height: 200px; background-color: orange;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" style="height: 600px; background-color: yellow;"></div>
        <div class="col" style="height: 300px; background-color: green;"></div>
        <div class="col" style="height: 400px; background-color: purple;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Your html structure should be

`<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" style="height: 900px; background-color: blue;"></div>
        <div class="col" style="height: 500px; background-color: red;"></div>
        <div class="col" style="height: 200px; background-color: orange;"></div>
        <div class="col" style="height: 600px; background-color: yellow;"></div>
        <div class="col" style="height: 300px; background-color: green;"></div>
        <div class="col" style="height: 400px; background-color: purple;"></div>
    </div>
</div>`

After include the Masonry .js file in your site. Initialize with jQuery

`$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.row').masonry({
          // options
          itemSelector: '.col',
          columnWidth: '.col'
        });
    });`

https://jsfiddle.net/a8ar7eyx/2/

Comment: I have been experimenting with masonry.  I would only want this to go into effect at certain breakpoints though.  The biggest issue that I was running into is that once this script has been executed, I cannot "unload" it.  If the person resizes the browser to a bigger breakpoint, I wouldn't want the masonry stuff to run.

Comment: I still prefer Masonry and I think you should look at [destroy method](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#destroy). Then you can use `$( window ).resize()` with your breakpoint to re-init or destroy masonry